# can a private data member of a class be used in data sharing clause in openMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

Referring to this: https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu105.html#x138-5520002.19.3
It states that, "A variable that is part of another variable (as an array or structure element) cannot be privatized except if the data-sharing attribute clause is associated with a construct within a class non-static member function and the variable is an accessible data member of the object for which the non-static member function is invoked."

I am not able to get this. Could anyone of you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you have a class `A`, which has a data member `x`:

```
class A {
      int x;
};

A a;
```

This rule concerns when `x` can be privatized. It states that a variable (`x)` that is a part of another variable (`a`), cannot be made private unless the data-sharing attribute clause (i.e. `private(x)` clause) is part of a **non-static member function** of a class. In this case, the variable `x` must also be **an accessible data member** (i.e. public) of the object for which the non-static member function is invoked. If these conditions are not met, the variable cannot be privatized.

Here, I show you examples:

a) In this example `x` is accessed from a non-static member function (`foo`) and `x` is accessible, so it can be compiled without any problem:

```
class A {
   public:
      int x;
      void foo() {
        //It is fine, a non-static member function can privatize an accessible data member
         #pragma omp parallel private(x) 
         {
            x = omp_get_thread_num();
         }
      }
};
```

b) However, a static member function cannot privatize `x`:

```
class A {
   public:
      int x;
      static void foo() {
        //Error, a static class member function cannot privatize x
         #pragma omp parallel private(x) 
         {
            x = omp_get_thread_num();
         }
      }
};
```

c)  non class member functions cannot privatize `x`:

```
class A {
      public:
      int x;
};

int main() {
   A a;
    
   // Error, only a class member function can privatize x 
   #pragma omp parallel private(a.x)
   {
       x = omp_get_thread_num();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to compile the code shown in section (a)?  because I am not able to compile using MSVC++. I am getting the error:  error C3028: 'A::x': only a variable or static data member can be used in a data-sharing clause. Also, what do you mean here accessible data member? The member function can always access the private data member, right? so why we need to declare it under 'public' access specifier? If I declare the data member as 'static' I am able to compile.

Comment: The problem is that you were referring to OpenMP 5.0 standard, but MSVC is only OpenMP 2.0 compatible. If you use a compiler with newer OpenMP standard (such as g++ or clang) you can compile the code in section a). Yes you are right, code in section c) should work. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/svEhqz5P7). I have modified my answer accordingly.